# activate google analytics on a React Application

Tags: linux, react-native, google-analytics, centos

i have a big commercial Application , this Application is written with `Laravel as Back-End` and `React as Front-End` , i searched the web for `how to activate google analytics in React` , and i found a couple of answers .

please first read the `Installation & Setup` part of this page ( its very short ) : https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-google-analytics-with-react-3d98d709399b

now because i'm working directly with the host console ( on the server `Linux centos7` ) . i can't make any mistake .

so my **question is :** where should i run the installation code and install the `react-ga` , in the `backend folder` OR in the `frontend folder` ?

*for example my laravel backend is installed in `/usr/share/nginx/html/backend/` & my React frontend is in `/var/www/website/src/containers/homepage`*

**in general** ? can someone please tell me how should i activate `Google Analitycs` for my `main (first) page` as according to the instruction of the Address i included in this question ?

**NOTE:** I am using `centos` and `nginx` as web server

**also, is there an easier solution to this question ?**

i will very much appreciate it .

Comment: **NOTE**: I am using `centos`, and my server is `Nginx`

Answer (score 0):

You have to run it in the frontend folder.

The easiest solution in my opinion is ***react-ga*** itself.

```
import ReactGA from 'react-ga';
ReactGA.initialize('UA-000000-01');
ReactGA.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```

Comment: i have a `source folder `, and i have a folder in which Compiled files are . in which of these two should i install this `npm` ?